# Highlight multiple gridview rows as one

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, gridview, highlight

A gridview displays as follows:

```
       FAMILY       GROUP              COLOR
===============================================
      |        |   Poodle           |  Blue
ROW1  | DOG    |   German Shepherd  |  Red
      |        |   Pitbull          |  Orange
===============================================
      |        |   Evil             |  green
ROW2  | CAT    |   tabby            |  purple
```

On mouse over I would like each row to be highlighted. Keep in mind, each listing in column "group" and "color" are a separate row. This means that "poodle" & "blue" are one row, the next row would be "german shepherd" and "red" so on and so forth.

I would like to have all those rows react as if they were a single row. Essentially each row will be based on the column "FAMILY". On mouse over I would like to have row1 (dog) highlighted, and all the rows in the columns "group" & "color", associated with DOG, be highlighted as well.

So far I have gotten each row to be highlighted on mouse over, as a single row, but I cannot figure out how to make similar rows act as a single entity on mouse over.

RENDERED HTML:

```
<table class="gridview" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="MainContent_gvAnimalInfo" style="width:90%;border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
       <th scope="col">
                  <a>FAMILY</a>
               </th>
               <th scope="col">GROUP</th>
               <th scope="col">COLOR</th>
    </tr>
            <tr>
        <td rowspan="3">DOG</td>
                <td>Poodle</td>
                <td>Blue</td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
         <td>German Shepherd</td>
                <td>Red</td>
    </tr>
            <tr>
         <td>Pitbull</td>
                <td>Orange</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Can you post the rendered HTML?

Comment: included now. i simplified it so that it would be easier to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give all your table rows a class of dog. Give the TD that houses the DOG label an ID of "dogLabel". This should take care of it:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".dog").hover(
            function () {
                $(this).css("background", "yellow");
                $("#dogLabel").css("background", "yellow");
        },
            function () {
                $(this).css("background", "");
                $("#dogLabel").css("background", "");
            }
        );
});
```

A fiddle as well: http://jsfiddle.net/qDYAP/1/

Comment: thank you. i updated the fiddle to highlight the whole row as one, regardless of where the mouse is on the row

Comment: how would i do that if the class will be generated dynamically from the code behind?

Comment: You can get the class attribute with .attr("class").